# R sampling with if statement and similar number of sample

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements, distribution, sample

I need to to create a sample from my dataframe and to do so I am using the code bellow.

```
 name <- sample(c("Adam","John","Henry","Mike"),100,rep = TRUE)
 area <- sample(c("run","develop","test"),100,rep = TRUE)
 id <- sample(100:200,100,rep = FALSE)

 mydata <- as.data.frame(cbind(id,area,name))


qcsample <- mydata %>%
  group_by(area) %>% 
  nest() %>%            
  mutate(n = c(20, 15, 15)) %>% 
  mutate(samp = map2(data, n, sample_n)) %>% 
  select(area, samp) %>%
  unnest()
```

Now, I am getting these results.

```
table(qcsample$area) 

develop     run    test 
     15      15      20
```

--

```
table(qcsample$name)

Adam Henry  John  Mike 

    9     9    16    16
```

I would like to create a sample that would have more or less the same number of samples for each name eg. Adam - 12, Henry - 12, John - 13, Mike - 13. 
How can I achieve that ? can I somehow request that the sample is equally distributed ?

Also, in this example I used function

> sample_n

and specified number of samples.

I am anticipating that sometimes there will not be required number from a given group. In my example I am taking 20 samples from area called "test" but sometimes there will be only let's say 10 rows containing "test". The total number is 50 so I need to make sure if there are only 10 "test" the code has to automatically increase the others, so the sample would be "test" - 10, "run" - 20 and "develop" - 20. This can happen to any of the area so I need to test if there is enough rows to create the sample and increase other areas. If there is only 1 it can be added to any of the remaining areas or if the difference is 3 we add 1 to one area and 2 to the another one.

How could I check that taking into account all the possibilities ? I believe there are eight permutations in this case.

Thanks in advance A.

Comment: In order to ensure near-equal proportions (i.e., intentionally reduce your randomness), you'll need to either (a) resample (an unknown number of times) until you get acceptable proportions; or (b) fix your proportions up-front and just sample the order of those names. You can't really "request" that random be less-random :-)

Comment: Thanks, I have fixed the numbers upfront ...  I will post my solution on a separate thread looking for a more elegant version as mine is a bit messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using made up data then you can create a minimum amount of each row and then create filler to get you up to the total:

```
set.seed(42)

names <- c("Adam", "John", "Henry", "Mike")
areas <- c("run", "develop", "test")

totalrows <- 100
minname   <-  22 # No less than 20 of each name (set to near threshold to test)
minarea   <-  30 # No less than 30 of each area (less randomness the higher these are)

qcsample <- data.frame(
  name=sample(c(rep(names, minname), sample(names, totalrows-length(names)*minname, replace=T))),
  area=sample(c(rep(areas, minarea), sample(areas, totalrows-length(areas)*minarea, replace=T))),
  id=sample(99+(1:totalrows))
)
```

This results in:

```
R> table(qcsample$name)

 Adam Henry  John  Mike 
   23    28    24    25 
R> table(qcsample$area)

develop     run    test 
     37      31      32
```

Notice that the count of `name` to `area` isn't constrained:

```
R> table(qcsample[,-3])
       area
name    develop run test
  Adam        5  11    7
  Henry      11   8    9
  John       10   7    7
  Mike       11   5    9
R>
```

**Using a loop as suggested by @r2evans:**

```
library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)

mydata <- data.frame(
  name = sample(c("Adam","John","Henry","Mike"), 100, rep = TRUE),
  area = sample(c("run","develop","test"), 100, rep = TRUE),
  id   = sample(100:200, 100, rep = FALSE)
)

Nsamples <- 50
mysample <- data.frame(sample_n(mydata, Nsamples))

minname <- 11  # max is 50/4 -> 12 
minarea <- 15  # max is 50/3 -> 16

# the test you were asking about
while( (min(table(mysample$name)) < minname) || (min(table(mysample$area)) < minarea) ) {
  mysample <- data.frame(sample_n(mydata, Nsamples))
}
```

This results in:

```
R> table(mysample$name)

 Adam Henry  John  Mike 
   13    15    11    11 

R> table(mysample$area)

develop     run    test 
     15      17      18
```

And, like before, there's no minimum of name to area.

```
R> table(mysample[-3])
       area
name    develop run test
  Adam        4   3    6
  Henry       2   6    7
  John        4   4    3
  Mike        5   4    2
```

If you needed to enforce an minimum number for each permutation add this to the test:

```
while(... || (min(table(mysample[-3])) < some_min)) {
```

BTW, the number of permutations, as you can see by the table, is the number of names times the number of areas.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I am using a real data and the provided example was just to explain what I am trying to achieve. The main thing is to have the required size of the sample, total of 50. Then maintain the percentage of 50, test 40%, run 30% and develop 30% which gives respectively 20,15,15. If there is not enough data for any of them I have to increase (more or less equally) other areas to have total of 50. All samples have to be unique hence I can't replace them.       Thnaks

Comment: I was afraid of that. I made one solution that sampled the minimum amount for each category then did sampling to fill out the rest, or remove rows as needed, but it was too ugly to post. Probably ANY other solution that someone came up with was more elegant than mine. :)   @r2evans "loop until you get the proportions you want" is probably the best.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know how to create an if statement to set a counter ? let's say i would first check if the first area size if 50. If it's 40 I would set my first counter to 40 and test another ones. If the second and third one are more than 50 I would say set 50 + 5 for each of them. 10 is remaining from the first one so I divided it by 2. If the number is odd let's say 9 i would need to split it into 4 and 5. I want to make the total number 150. I would need to test all the possibilities across the three areas. Then I could get a percentage sample from them. Many thanks !

Comment: Editing the original answer to include such a test.

Comment: Well, I guess the short answer is "no, I don't know how to do such a test.", but, I don't think that's the way to go.

Comment: Also, it's possible that with a different seed you'd not be able to meet the minimums. You should probably check that it's possible before you start the while loop!

Comment: Many thanks!  As soon as I have more time at work I will test it on the real data and let you know how I got on. Much appreciated! :)

Comment: Hi, so finally I got time to implement the code to my data and run some tests ... the only condition for the while loop i set for (min(table(mysample[-3])) < 1) ...  the loop never stops :( it runs for ever ... my data set is bigger than the example but even on the example set the while loop never stops ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's another thought.

Depending on your desired end-size, it might over-create the number of samples so that it can reduce some name/area pairs to bring the total down.

Let's say that you want to end up with a total of 50 rows:

```
final_size <- 50
```

For completeness, here are the sets from which we'll choose:

```
avail_names <- c("Adam", "John", "Henry", "Mike")
avail_areas <- c("run", "develop", "test")
```

and the minimum we need to create for `Adam,run` (etc) in order to *certainly* end up with no less than `final_size` rows:

```
size_per_namearea <- ceiling(final_size / (length(avail_names) * length(avail_areas)))
```

Ok, generate at least as many (likely more than) the number of rows we need:

```
set.seed(20180920)
qcsample <- crossing(data_frame(rownum = seq_len(size_per_namearea)),
                     data_frame(name   = avail_names),
                     data_frame(area   = avail_areas)) %>%
  group_by(name, area) %>%
  mutate(id = sample(100, size = n(), replace = FALSE))
qcsample
# # A tibble: 60 x 4
# # Groups:   name, area [12]
#    rownum name  area       id
#     <int> <chr> <chr>   <int>
#  1      1 Adam  run        59
#  2      1 Adam  develop    51
#  3      1 Adam  test       23
#  4      1 John  run        71
#  5      1 John  develop     5
#  6      1 John  test       24
#  7      1 Henry run         4
#  8      1 Henry develop    29
#  9      1 Henry test       79
# 10      1 Mike  run        77
# # ... with 50 more rows
```

Verify we have identical sample sizes for each name/area:

```
xtabs(~ name + area, data = qcsample) %>%
  stats::addmargins()
#        area
# name    develop run test Sum
#   Adam        5   5    5  15
#   Henry       5   5    5  15
#   John        5   5    5  15
#   Mike        5   5    5  15
#   Sum        20  20   20  60
```

If we just do `head(final_size)`, then we *know* which names we will be cutting short, which undermines the randomness of your sampling a little. The reason I added `rownum` up front was so that I can arrange by it *plus a jitter*, ensuring I get all of `max(rownum)-1`, and then some sampling of `max(rownum)`, *guaranteeing* that each name/area pair have either `max(rownum)-1` or `max(rownum)` rows; your tallies are never different by more than 1.

```
reducedsample <- arrange(qcsample, rownum + runif(n()))  %>%
  head(final_size) %>%
  select(-rownum)
reducedsample %>%
  xtabs(~ name + area, data = .) %>%
  stats::addmargins()
#        area
# name    develop run test Sum
#   Adam        4   4    5  13
#   Henry       5   4    4  13
#   John        4   4    4  12
#   Mike        4   4    4  12
#   Sum        17  16   17  50
```